# Rails 3.1. Capybara's Selenium driver doesn't catch the routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, webdriver

When I use the `visit` method in Cucumber's step definitions and then run the step through Capybara's Selenium driver it's passed despite the controller isn't implemented.

Here's an example:

**Feature**

```
# features/one.feature

Feature: One

  @selenium
  Scenario: One
    Given I visit the example page
```

**Step definition**

```
# features/step_definitions/example_steps.rb

Given /^I visit the example page$/ do
  visit example_path
end
```

**Route**

```
# config/routes.rb

Example::Application.routes.draw do
  resource :example
end
```

**Controller**

*isn't implemented*

**Result**

```
Feature: One

    @selenium
    Scenario: One
      Given I visit the example page

    1 scenario (1 passed)
    1 step (1 passed)
    0m18.162s
```

However, when I use the RackTest driver all works as it expected to be and the routing exception is risen unless a controller is implemented.

Here's the same example but with the usage of RackTest:

**Feature**

```
# features/one.feature

Feature: One

  @rack_test
  Scenario: One
    Given I visit the example page
```

**Result**

```
Feature: One

  @rack_test
  Scenario: One
    Given I visit the example page
      uninitialized constant ExamplesController (ActionController::RoutingError)
      ./features/step_definitions/example_steps.rb:2:in `/^I visit the example page$/'
      features/one.feature:5:in `Given I visit the example page'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/one.feature:4 # Scenario: One

1 scenario (1 failed)
1 step (1 failed)
```

How can I force Capybara to raise the routing error when using the Selenium driver?

Thanks.

Ruby 1.9.2;

Ruby on Rails 3.1.0.rc1;

Cucumber 0.10.3;

Cucumber-rails 0.5.0;

Capybara 1.0.0.beta1;

Selenium-webdriver 0.2.0.

Comment: What happens when you try to view the page locally through your browser (i.e. http://localhost:3000/example )

Comment: I get the Routing Error message.

Answer (score 1):

The Selenium driver does not fail when it receives a "failure" http code like 500. If you left your config/environments/test.rb at it's defaults, there should be a line config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false. So you can either set this to true or you would have to add some more steps to ensure the page is actually showing what you expect.